# Calculate mean of the distribution which is a function of normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Calculate mean of random variable $\max\{exp\{-\frac{7}{800}\},exp\{\frac{Z}{4}\}\}$, where $Z$ is normally distributed with variance 1 and mean 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y=\max\{\exp(-\frac{7}{800}),\exp(\frac{Z}{4})\}=\begin{cases}\exp(-\frac{7}{800}),& -\frac{7}{800}\ge\frac{Z}{4}\\
\exp(\frac{Z}{4}),& -\frac{7}{800}<\frac{Z}{4}
\end{cases}$$

$-\frac{7}{800}=\frac{z}{4}\Rightarrow z=-\frac 7 {200}$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}E[Y]&=\exp(-\frac{7}{800})\Pr(Z<-\frac 7 {200})+E[\exp(\frac{Z}{4}), z\ge-\frac 7 {200}]
\\&=\exp(-\frac{7}{800})\int^{-\frac 7 {200}}_{-\infty}\phi(z)dz+\int_{-\frac 7 {200}}^{\infty}\exp(\frac{z}{4})\phi(z)dz\\
&=  0.9913\left(1-Q\left(-\frac{7}{200}\right)\right)+e^{1/32}Q\left(-\frac{7}{200}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\
\end{align}$$

where $\phi(z)$ is the standard Gaussian pdf and $Q$ is the complementary cdf.

Comment: msm, thanks, but this is only a part of solution ;-) I had problems with transforming the last integral into a function of $\Phi(x)$ for suitable $x$, in order to use statistical tables.